# Cannot get attribute value when using xpath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, xpath

I met a problem when I try to get an attribute of one tag.

Here is the html code:

```
<rect x="66.5" y="43.5" width="26" height="13" fill="#86E067" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point "></rect>
```

Here is the xpath for that html:

```
//*[@id="highcharts-z14trt3-4"]/svg/g[6]/g[1]/rect[2].
```

I copied this xpath from Chrome directly,

I am trying to get the attribute **height**, and here is what I did:

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]/svg/g[6]/g[1]/rect[2]"));
```

I cannot use tagName as there are many tags called rect. Meanwhile, I cannot use the exactly same XPath as the id is dynamic.

So the result is that selenium says cannot locate the element.

Is the way I try to locate this element wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: If possible also post your exception text and the full HTML or a URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svg` has a *default namespace* `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`. You need to handle [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). Either with a prefix:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]/svg:svg/svg:g[6]/svg:g[1]/svg:rect[2]
```

Or, with [`local-name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name):

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]/*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[local-name() = 'g'][6]/*[local-name() = 'g'][1]/*[local-name() = 'rect'][2]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**
Your XPath is not valid. You are missing a `'` after the word `highcharts`.

**Solution 2:**
You are using `findElement`. Can you try using an explicit wait for the element to become visible? If your implicit waiting time is 0, `findElement` immediately throws an exception (it doesn't retry) which is understandable if your `rect` isn't loaded already when your page is ready.

Comment: I was trying $x('*//svg:svg') on the website demo.bpmn.io but can't get it to work. I opened a question for this on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34437/how-to-investigate-svg-objects-in-dom-with-xpath